# GnuRadio additive scrambling/descrambling

Tags: gnuradio, software-defined-radio

How are you supposed to use GNU Radio additive scrambler block? The [wiki documentation](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Additive_Scrambler) is very vague on the subject:

> Scramble an input stream using a Linear Feedback Shift Register
> (LFSR).
>
> This block scrambles up to 8 bits per byte of the input data stream,
> starting at the LSB. The scrambler works by XORing the incoming bit
> stream by the output of the LFSR. Optionally, after bits have been
> processed, the shift register is reset to the value. This allows
> processing fixed length vectors of samples.
>
> Alternatively, the LFSR can be reset using a reset tag to scramble
> variable length vectors. However, it cannot be reset between bytes.
>
> For details on configuring the LFSR, see [gr::digital::lfsr](https://www.gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/classgr_1_1digital_1_1lfsr.html).

In my university SDR lab, there is some data being transmitted and I have to fully demodulate and decode it.

I'm currently stuck at descrambling data. It is known that additive scrambler is used and its polynomial is $1+x^{-14}+x^{-15}$ with initial state is **010111111111111**. I've identified sync word in data stream so I know where to start descrambling but I have trouble configuring additive scrambler block.

Could someone with more knowledge explain how to use it and maybe post an example?

For example should I input polynomial $1+x^{-14}+x^{-15}$ as $1100000000000001_2=C001_{16}$ (as [GNU Radio Manual and C++ API Reference](https://www.gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/classgr_1_1digital_1_1lfsr.html) suggests) or as $1000000000000011{2}=4003_{16}$ (as [Daniel Estévez](https://destevez.net/2016/05/scramblers-and-their-implementation-in-gnuradio/) suggests) Same for seed value. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Could you explain what specifically you don't understand about the documentation?

Comment: Hi! For example should I input polynomial $1+x^{-14}+x^{-15}$ as $1100000000000001_2 = C001_{16}$ (as [GNU Radio Manual and C++ API Reference](https://www.gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/classgr_1_1digital_1_1lfsr.html) suggests) or as $1000000000000011_2 = 4003_{16}$ (as [Daniel Estévez](https://destevez.net/2016/05/scramblers-and-their-implementation-in-gnuradio/) suggests). Same for seed value. Thanks!